# Illegal conversion from String to Boolean

Tags: apex, developer-console, developer

Hope all are doing good!

I'm facing an issue on returning the error messages on top of page if the field value is BLANK.
Kindly please check below  code once correct me if I'm doing wrong at anypoint.

```
public static final String REGULATOR_ERROR = 'Regulator field can\'t be BLANK';
public static final String REASON_FOR_NOT_CATEGORY_ERROR = 'Reason for not scope field can\'t be BLANK';

@AuraEnabled
public static boolean updateRecord(String IoCaseOrgid, String categoryValue, String CategoryReason) {
    List<IO_Case__c> lstIoCases = new List<IO_Case__c>();
    for (IO_Case__c io : [SELECT Id, Name, Onboarding_Reason_for_Not_Scope__c, Onboard_Categories__c, Onboard_BIC_Code__c, Onboard_Regulator_Name__c, Onboard_Group_Compliance_Email_Attached__c
                         FROM IO_Case__c WHERE io_Organisation_ID__c = :IoCaseOrgid]) {
        if (categoryValue == 'Not applicable') {
            if (String.isBlank(io.Onboarding_Reason_for_Not_Scope__c) == true) {
                // Even though Onboarding_Reason_for_Not_Scope__c field is BLANK not returning error message
                return REASON_FOR_NOT_CATEGORY_ERROR;   
            } else {
                io.Onboard_Categories__c = categoryValue;
                io.Onboarding_Reason_for_Not_Scope__c = CategoryReason;
                io.Onboard_Regulator_Name__c = '';
                io.Onboard_Group_Compliance_Email_Attached__c = '';
                lstIoCases.add(io);
            }
        } else if (categoryValue == 'Category A') {
            if (String.isBlank(io.Onboard_Regulator_Name__c) == true) {
                // Even though Onboard_Regulator_Name__c field is BLANK not returning error message
                return REGULATOR_ERROR; 
            } else {
                io.Onboard_Categories__c = categoryValue;
                io.Onboarding_Reason_for_Not_Scope__c = '';
                io.Onboard_Group_Compliance_Email_Attached__c = ''; 
                lstIoCases.add(io);
            }
        }
    }
    if (lstIoCases.size() > 0) {
        Update lstIoCases;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've seen your code there are **Two Lines** where you are retuning String Values from method that should return a boolean value

`return REASON_FOR_NOT_CATEGORY_ERROR;`

`return REGULATOR_ERROR;`

What you can an do is either replace then with

`throw new AuraHandledException(REASON_FOR_NOT_CATEGORY_ERROR);`

`throw new AuraHandledException(REGULATOR_ERROR);`

**Or**

inside your method `updateRecord` at the top you can define global Boolean Variable and set it to false

`boolean isRecordUpdated = false;`

and replace `return REASON_FOR_NOT_CATEGORY_ERROR;` and  `return REGULATOR_ERROR;` with `isRecordUpdated =false;`

Then in when you update lstIoCases add `isRecordUpdated =true;` and in else add `isRecordUpdated =false;`

Example

```
@AuraEnabled
public static boolean updateRecord(String IoCaseOrgid, String categoryValue, String CategoryReason) {
boolean isRecordUpdated = false;
List<IO_Case__c> lstIoCases = new List<IO_Case__c>();

for (IO_Case__c io : [SELECT Id, Name, Onboarding_Reason_for_Not_Scope__c, Onboard_Categories__c, Onboard_BIC_Code__c, Onboard_Regulator_Name__c, Onboard_Group_Compliance_Email_Attached__c 
                      FROM IO_Case__c 
                      WHERE io_Organisation_ID__c = :IoCaseOrgid]) {
    if (categoryValue == 'Not applicable') {
        if (String.isBlank(io.Onboarding_Reason_for_Not_Scope__c)) {
            // Even though Onboarding_Reason_for_Not_Scope__c field is BLANK not returning error message
            isRecordUpdated = false;
            break;   
        } else {
            io.Onboard_Categories__c = categoryValue;
            io.Onboarding_Reason_for_Not_Scope__c = CategoryReason;
            io.Onboard_Regulator_Name__c = '';
            io.Onboard_Group_Compliance_Email_Attached__c = '';
            lstIoCases.add(io);
        }
    } else if (categoryValue == 'Category A') {
        if (String.isBlank(io.Onboard_Regulator_Name__c)) {
            // Even though Onboard_Regulator_Name__c field is BLANK not returning error message
            isRecordUpdated = false;
            break; 
        } else {
            io.Onboard_Categories__c = categoryValue;
            io.Onboarding_Reason_for_Not_Scope__c = '';
            io.Onboard_Group_Compliance_Email_Attached__c = ''; 
            lstIoCases.add(io);
        }
    }
}

if (lstIoCases.size() > 0) {
    update lstIoCases;
    isRecordUpdated = true;
} else {
    isRecordUpdated = false;
}

return isRecordUpdated;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Step1 : I have added Exception lines as suggested but those are not showing like errors on page once I clicked on submit button.

As Step2: I have tries by Return false  step also this is also skipping the execution but not showing like errors in screen like Toast

Comment: I have Edited My Answerer Please check again